# Finding limits using the sandwich rule

Tags: limits, analysis

In order to find $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\sqrt{\lvert{x}\rvert}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ using the sandwich rule, is the following correct:

$$\bigg\lvert\sqrt{\lvert x \rvert}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\bigg\rvert\leqslant \big\lvert\sqrt{\lvert x \rvert}\big\rvert\\-\sqrt{\lvert x \rvert}\leqslant\sqrt{\lvert x \rvert}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\leqslant\sqrt{\lvert x \rvert} \text{   if x>0}\\\text{so by the sandwich rule:}\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\sqrt{\lvert{x}\rvert}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=0$$

Need I remove the absolute value operators from the left and right-hand side terms in the second line?

Comment: yes its correct.

Answer (score 1):

In the first line, the outer absolute value of the RHS is redundant.

In the second line, you just need $x \ne 0$ rather than $x>0$.

$$0 \le \left|\sqrt{|x|}\sin \left(\frac1{x}\right) \right| \le \sqrt{|x|}$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0}0 \le \lim_{x \to 0}\left|\sqrt{|x|}\sin \left(\frac1{x}\right) \right| \le \lim_{x \to 0}\sqrt{|x|}$$

$$0 \le \lim_{x \to 0}\left|\sqrt{|x|}\sin \left(\frac1{x}\right) \right| \le 0$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt{|x|}\sin \frac1{x}=0$$